# Handling MVC form submission to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I'm loosely following the Music Store tutorial. I created the StoreManagerController on pg. 54ish. And it created a view with the Create, Deleted, Edit, etc. It's saving some stuff to the database, namely my EditFor controls, but nothing else.

I have multiple DropDownListFor controls, populated by both tables in the database and also Active Directory user data. I'm not sure how to get these to save. Here is my abridged code. Thanks for the help.

View:

```
<div class="createTopInner">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.test.Category)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoryItems, "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.test.Category)
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // These four lines get active directory users
    ActiveDirectoryModel ads = new ActiveDirectoryModel();
    ViewBag.assignedto = ads.FetchContacts();
    ViewBag.coassignedto = ads.FetchContacts();
    ViewBag.notifyto = ads.FetchContacts();
    var model = Populate();
    return View(model);
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TestItems.AddObject(model.test);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    return View(model);
}

public CreateViewModel Populate()
{
    var model = new CreateViewModel
    {
        CategoryItems =
            from c in new IntraEntities().CategoryItems.ToList()
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.Name,
                Value = c.ID.ToString()
            }
    };
    return model;
}
```

Model:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public Intra.Models.TestItem test{ get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that, while most of your inputs map to properties on `test`, the `CategoryId` doesn't.  Not knowing anything about your entity models, it's difficult to say, but I'd hazard a guess that you need to retrieve the corresponding `Category` from the database and add that to your `TestItem` instance before you persist it.  If you do have a `CategoryId` property on your `TestItem` instance, you could just set it, but I'm guessing that you don't because otherwise you would have used it directly (as you do for the `Category` label) instead of adding a property to the view model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to it / know much about stored procedures, it is much better to use Store procedures inside the database and then call them within Entity. It's much more loosely coupled and easier to make changes to without recompiling code.